# Stripe subscription with Apple Pay

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay, flutter-stripe

I’m trying to setup a payment method for a subscription on mobile with flutter and .net as backend.

For that here is my flow :

- I create a customer and a SetupIntent backend side
- I send the details to flutter and it present the payment sheet to customer letting him choose Apple Pay as a payment method
- when SetupIntent is completed mobile side I’m listening for it on web-hook backend side and I create the subscription with a trial period and the SetupIntent Id just created.

It works pretty well but I have a problem with apple validation.

When customer choose Apple Pay as a payment method It display « amount pending » instead of the subscription plan price and recurrence. Which is normal since I didn’t create the subscription at this step. But it’s rejected by Apple.

I checked the  SetupIntent to see if I can attach a subscription to it to let the pricing appear but it seems not.

I checked the doc and the only sample I see is related to checkout portal but I want to use the element payment sheet to the customer.

As you can see in the Apple guide it should be display like the first screenshot of this page : https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/apple-pay/overview/subscriptions-and-donations/

Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

Comment: You get "Amount pending" because you're using a SetupIntent. I wouldn't use the SetupIntent at all. You should instead be creating the Subscription first, then getting `subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret`, and you use _that_ with the PaymentSheet on the frontend (it would show the amount of the first invoice in the Apple Pay popup). i..e the overall flow at https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements

Comment: @karlleko Thanks for your reply, I tried but it seems payment intent is null maybe because I have a trial period set. But I would like to setup payment method even if there is a free period

Comment: @karllekko ok, so when there is a trial period it's field `subscription?.PendingSetupIntent?.ClientSecret` with `subscriptionOptions.AddExpand("pending_setup_intent");`. But unfortunately I face the same problem as with setup intent and apple pay. It still display "Amount Pending"...

Comment: Yeah if you're using a trial period I'm not aware of any way to get this to work differently with the way that Stripe's API works. I'm surprised Apple would reject the app, probably worth reaching out to Stripe support since their default integrations should operate in ways that allow for this. (unfortunately Stripe doesn't seem to have first-class support for subscriptions+Apple Pay in their default integration, you _can_ use the Invoice PaymentIntent or the Subscription SetupIntent in the PaymentSheet but it's not documented)